# Gather multiple sets of columns

Tags: r, reshape, dplyr, qualtrics, tidyr

I have data from an online survey where respondents go through a loop of questions 1-3 times. The survey software (Qualtrics) records this data in multiple columns—that is, Q3.2 in the survey will have columns `Q3.2.1.`, `Q3.2.2.`, and `Q3.2.3.`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  Q3.2.1. = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Q3.2.2. = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Q3.2.3. = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Q3.3.1. = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Q3.3.2. = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Q3.3.3. = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
)

# Sample data

   id       time    Q3.2.1.     Q3.2.2.    Q3.2.3.     Q3.3.1.    Q3.3.2.     Q3.3.3.
1   1 2009-01-01 -0.2059165 -0.29177677 -0.7107192  1.52718069 -0.4484351 -1.21550600
2   2 2009-01-02 -0.1981136 -1.19813815  1.1750200 -0.40380049 -1.8376094  1.03588482
3   3 2009-01-03  0.3514795 -0.27425539  1.1171712 -1.02641801 -2.0646661 -0.35353058
...
```

I want to combine all the QN.N* columns into tidy individual QN.N columns, ultimately ending up with something like this:

```
   id       time loop_number        Q3.2        Q3.3
1   1 2009-01-01           1 -0.20591649  1.52718069
2   2 2009-01-02           1 -0.19811357 -0.40380049
3   3 2009-01-03           1  0.35147949 -1.02641801
...
11  1 2009-01-01           2 -0.29177677  -0.4484351
12  2 2009-01-02           2 -1.19813815  -1.8376094
13  3 2009-01-03           2 -0.27425539  -2.0646661
...
21  1 2009-01-01           3 -0.71071921 -1.21550600
22  2 2009-01-02           3  1.17501999  1.03588482
23  3 2009-01-03           3  1.11717121 -0.35353058
...
```

The `tidyr` library has the `gather()` function, which works great for combining *one* set of columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% gather(loop_number, Q3.2, starts_with("Q3.2")) %>% 
  mutate(loop_number = str_sub(loop_number,-2,-2)) %>%
  select(id, time, loop_number, Q3.2)


   id       time loop_number        Q3.2
1   1 2009-01-01           1 -0.20591649
2   2 2009-01-02           1 -0.19811357
3   3 2009-01-03           1  0.35147949
...
29  9 2009-01-09           3 -0.58581232
30 10 2009-01-10           3 -2.33393981
```

The resultant data frame has 30 rows, as expected (10 individuals, 3 loops each). However, gathering a second set of columns does not work correctly—it successfully makes the two combined columns `Q3.2` and `Q3.3`, but ends up with 90 rows instead of 30 (all combinations of 10 individuals, 3 loops of Q3.2, and 3 loops of Q3.3; the combinations will increase substantially for each group of columns in the actual data):

```
df %>% gather(loop_number, Q3.2, starts_with("Q3.2")) %>% 
  gather(loop_number, Q3.3, starts_with("Q3.3")) %>%
  mutate(loop_number = str_sub(loop_number,-2,-2))


   id       time loop_number        Q3.2        Q3.3
1   1 2009-01-01           1 -0.20591649  1.52718069
2   2 2009-01-02           1 -0.19811357 -0.40380049
3   3 2009-01-03           1  0.35147949 -1.02641801
...
89  9 2009-01-09           3 -0.58581232 -0.13187024
90 10 2009-01-10           3 -2.33393981 -0.48502131
```

Is there a way to use multiple calls to `gather()` like this, combining small subsets of columns like this while maintaining the correct number of rows?

Comment: what's wrong with `df %>% gather(loop_number, Q3.2, starts_with("Q3."))`

Comment: That gets me one consolidated column with 60 rows. I guess that could work if I then included some sort of call to `seperate()` to divide up the Q3.3 (and beyond) values into their own columns. But that still seems like a really roundabout hacky solution…

Comment: use `spread` i am working on a solution now :p

Comment: try this! `df %>% gather(question_number, Q3.2, starts_with("Q3.")) %>% 
    mutate(loop_number = str_sub(question_number,-2,-2),
           question_number = str_sub(question_number,1,4)) %>%
    select(id, time, loop_number, question_number, Q3.2) %>%
    spread(key = question_number, value = Q3.2)`

Comment: Ooh, that works really well for the two variables. I'm curious if it's scalable though—in my real data I've got Q3.2-Q3.30, so it would need a bunch of individual calls to `spread()`. Though multiple calls appears inevitable anyway, whether it's a bunch of `generate()`s that work or nested `spread()`s…

Comment: @akrun figured out a scalable version below, with `gather` + `separate` + `spread`. Magic stuff.

Comment: my code should work for any number of questions, since the question number column will have distinct `Q3.2, Q3.3, ..., Q3.30`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread it and thought that in `spread(..., value=X)`, I would need to set `X` to each of the final column names. But that's definitely not the case.

Comment: +1 great question. FWIW, it's neither natural nor that efficient to have to melt (gather) the whole data set only to cast (spread) back. I'll post an answer if I manage to succeed implementing melt to accomplish this directly as required in this scenario.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

This approach seems pretty natural to me:

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -id, -time) %>%
  extract(key, c("question", "loop_number"), "(Q.\\..)\\.(.)") %>%
  spread(question, value)
```

First gather all question columns, use `extract()` to separate into `question` and `loop_number`, then `spread()` question back into the columns.

```
#>    id       time loop_number         Q3.2        Q3.3
#> 1   1 2009-01-01           1  0.142259203 -0.35842736
#> 2   1 2009-01-01           2  0.061034802  0.79354061
#> 3   1 2009-01-01           3 -0.525686204 -0.67456611
#> 4   2 2009-01-02           1 -1.044461185 -1.19662936
#> 5   2 2009-01-02           2  0.393808163  0.42384717
```

Comment: Hello.
I have many columns with names ending in 1 and 2, like  age1, age2, weight1, weight2, blood1, blood2....  How would I apply your method here?

Comment: What does this part mean: "(Q.\\..)\\.(.)"
What would I search for to decode what is happening there?

Comment: @mob Regular expressions

Comment: @mob "(Q.\\..)\\.(.)" is a regular expression with parentheses that define the groups of the regular expression to extract into "question" and "loop_number". More specifically, in this example, the items in key with the expression "Q.\\.." goes into the "question" column (i.e., "Q3.2" and "Q3.3"), then the part after next period, expressed as ".", goes into the "loop_number" column.

Answer (score 35):

This could be done using `reshape`.  It is possible with `dplyr` though.

```
  colnames(df) <- gsub("\\.(.{2})$", "_\\1", colnames(df))
  colnames(df)[2] <- "Date"
  res <- reshape(df, idvar=c("id", "Date"), varying=3:8, direction="long", sep="_")
  row.names(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
  
   head(res)
  #  id       Date time       Q3.2       Q3.3
  #1  1 2009-01-01    1  1.3709584  0.4554501
  #2  2 2009-01-02    1 -0.5646982  0.7048373
  #3  3 2009-01-03    1  0.3631284  1.0351035
  #4  4 2009-01-04    1  0.6328626 -0.6089264
  #5  5 2009-01-05    1  0.4042683  0.5049551
  #6  6 2009-01-06    1 -0.1061245 -1.7170087
```

Or   using `dplyr`

```
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)
  colnames(df) <- gsub("\\.(.{2})$", "_\\1", colnames(df))

  df %>%
     gather(loop_number, "Q3", starts_with("Q3")) %>% 
     separate(loop_number,c("L1", "L2"), sep="_") %>% 
     spread(L1, Q3) %>%
     select(-L2) %>%
     head()
  #  id       time       Q3.2       Q3.3
  #1  1 2009-01-01  1.3709584  0.4554501
  #2  1 2009-01-01  1.3048697  0.2059986
  #3  1 2009-01-01 -0.3066386  0.3219253
  #4  2 2009-01-02 -0.5646982  0.7048373
  #5  2 2009-01-02  2.2866454 -0.3610573
  #6  2 2009-01-02 -1.7813084 -0.7838389
```

#### Update

With new version of `tidyr`, we can use `pivot_longer` to reshape multiple columns.  (Using the changed column names from `gsub` above)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Q3"), 
          names_to = c(".value", "Q3"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
    select(-Q3)
# A tibble: 30 x 4
#      id time         Q3.2    Q3.3
#   <int> <date>      <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1 2009-01-01  0.974  1.47  
# 2     1 2009-01-01 -0.849 -0.513 
# 3     1 2009-01-01  0.894  0.0442
# 4     2 2009-01-02  2.04  -0.553 
# 5     2 2009-01-02  0.694  0.0972
# 6     2 2009-01-02 -1.11   1.85  
# 7     3 2009-01-03  0.413  0.733 
# 8     3 2009-01-03 -0.896 -0.271 
#9     3 2009-01-03  0.509 -0.0512
#10     4 2009-01-04  1.81   0.668 
# … with 20 more rows
```

NOTE: Values are different because there was no set seed in creating the input dataset

Comment: Whoa, this works perfectly. tidyr is ostensibly a replacement/upgrade for reshape--I wonder if @hadley knows of a way to do this same thing with dplyr or tidyr…

Comment: That is pure magic. The only thing I added was `mutate(loop_number = as.numeric(L2))` before dropping `L2`, and it's perfect.

Comment: @Andrew  I personally prefer the `reshape` method for its compact code, though `dplyr` may be faster for big datasets.

Comment: I've never been able to understand the `reshape()` function, see my solution for what I seems to me a pretty clean tidyr implementation.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer`: Now not only in the development version :)

Answer (score 22):

With the recent update to `melt.data.table`, we can now melt multiple columns. With that, we can do:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5
melt(setDT(df), id=1:2, measure=patterns("^Q3.2", "^Q3.3"), 
     value.name=c("Q3.2", "Q3.3"), variable.name="loop_number")
 #    id       time loop_number         Q3.2        Q3.3
 # 1:  1 2009-01-01           1 -0.433978480  0.41227209
 # 2:  2 2009-01-02           1 -0.567995351  0.30701144
 # 3:  3 2009-01-03           1 -0.092041353 -0.96024077
 # 4:  4 2009-01-04           1  1.137433487  0.60603396
 # 5:  5 2009-01-05           1 -1.071498263 -0.01655584
 # 6:  6 2009-01-06           1 -0.048376809  0.55889996
 # 7:  7 2009-01-07           1 -0.007312176  0.69872938
```

You can get the development version from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: Hello.
I have many columns with names ending in 1 and 2, like  age1, age2, weight1, weight2, blood1, blood2....  How would I apply your method here?

Comment: skan, check the [reshaping vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). Good luck!

Comment: I did but I don't know how to properly embed regular expressions to split column names and pass it to melt. There is only one example with patterns, and it's too simple.
In my case I would need to include many many column names inside pattern()

Comment: Imagine you have these columns: paste0(rep(LETTERS, each=3), 1:3) and you want to get the long table defined by a letter and a number

Comment: This is hands down the most succinct and easy to interpret.

Answer (score 10):

It's not at all related to "tidyr" and "dplyr", but here's another option to consider: `merged.stack` from [my "splitstackshape" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape), V1.4.0 and above.

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(df, id.vars = c("id", "time"), 
             var.stubs = c("Q3.2.", "Q3.3."),
             sep = "var.stubs")
#     id       time .time_1       Q3.2.       Q3.3.
#  1:  1 2009-01-01      1. -0.62645381  1.35867955
#  2:  1 2009-01-01      2.  1.51178117 -0.16452360
#  3:  1 2009-01-01      3.  0.91897737  0.39810588
#  4:  2 2009-01-02      1.  0.18364332 -0.10278773
#  5:  2 2009-01-02      2.  0.38984324 -0.25336168
#  6:  2 2009-01-02      3.  0.78213630 -0.61202639
#  7:  3 2009-01-03      1. -0.83562861  0.38767161
# <<:::SNIP:::>>
# 24:  8 2009-01-08      3. -1.47075238 -1.04413463
# 25:  9 2009-01-09      1.  0.57578135  1.10002537
# 26:  9 2009-01-09      2.  0.82122120 -0.11234621
# 27:  9 2009-01-09      3. -0.47815006  0.56971963
# 28: 10 2009-01-10      1. -0.30538839  0.76317575
# 29: 10 2009-01-10      2.  0.59390132  0.88110773
# 30: 10 2009-01-10      3.  0.41794156 -0.13505460
#     id       time .time_1       Q3.2.       Q3.3.
```

Comment: Hello.
I have many columns with names ending in 1 and 2, like  age1, age2, weight1, weight2, blood1, blood2....  How would I apply your method here?

Answer (score 6):

In case you are like me, and cannot work out how to use "regular expression with capturing groups" for `extract`, the following code replicates the `extract(...)` line in Hadleys' answer:

```
df %>% 
    gather(question_number, value, starts_with("Q3.")) %>%
    mutate(loop_number = str_sub(question_number,-2,-2), question_number = str_sub(question_number,1,4)) %>%
    select(id, time, loop_number, question_number, value) %>% 
    spread(key = question_number, value = value)
```

The problem here is that the initial gather forms a key column that is actually a combination of two keys. I chose to use `mutate` in my original solution in the comments to split this column into two columns with equivalent info, a `loop_number` column and a `question_number` column. `spread` can then be used to transform the long form data, which are key value pairs `(question_number, value)` to wide form data.