# how do I gather 2 sets of columns in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following structure:

```
key | category_x | 2009 | category_y | 2010
test
```

example data as requested

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(
key = 1:10,
category_x = paste0("stock_", 0:9),
'2008' = rnorm(10, 0, 10),
category_y = paste0("stock_", 0:9),
'2009' = rnorm(10, 0, 10),
category_z = paste0("stock_", 0:9),
'2010' = rnorm(10, 0, 10),
check.names=FALSE
)
```

how do I change that into:

```
key | category | year
```

I know I can use:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% gather(key, category, starts_with("category_"))
```

but that doesn't deal with the year. 
I looked at [Gather multiple sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns-with-tidyr#comment40585659_25925556)

but I don't get the extract spread commands.

Comment: how do I generate random strings for you to test then?

Comment: yup fixed the paste command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `gather`, we can do this in two steps.  First, we reshape from 'wide' to 'long' format for the column names that starts with 'category' and in the next step, we do the same with the numeric column names by selecting with `matches`.  The `matches` can regex patterns, so a pattern of `^[0-9]+$` means we match one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) of string.  We can remove the columns that are not needed with `select`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) 
gather(df, key, category, starts_with('category_')) %>%
     gather(key2, year, matches('^[0-9]+$')) %>%
     select(-starts_with('key'))
```

---

Or using the devel version of `data.table`, this would be much easier as the `melt` can take multiple patterns for `measure` columns.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), use `melt` and specify the `patterns` with in the `measure` argument.  We also have options to change the column names of the 'value' column.  The 'variable' column is set to NULL as it was not needed in the expected output.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
melt(setDT(df), measure=patterns(c('^category', '^[0-9]+$')), 
           value.name=c('category', 'year'))[, variable:=NULL][]
```

Comment: tidy version yields incorrect result