# how to use gather() in a for loop in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, tidyr

I have a big data set of 72 columns and I want to gather each 3 of columns into a new column and thus getting 24 columns in the end.

I tried using `gather()` function but it works good for one time only t=i.e., it gather only 3 columns at a time.

Can I use this function in a for loop?

I tried this:

```
j=0
k=1
l=2
for (i in 2:24){
  neww <- gather(columns, "KEy", "Proteins H/L", c((i+j), (i+k), (i+l)), na.rm = TRUE)
  j=j+2;
  k=k+2;
  l=l+2;
}
```

I need to gather first 3 columns in a single column and then next 3 in another column and so on.

Comment: Please produce a reproducible example. the `gather()` function is not part of base R. What package does it come from? Are you appending columns to make a data.frame 3 times as long, or are you pasting the columns together? Without more information, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: If you use the SE version `gather_`, you can iterate over the column names, which you can pass it as strings.

Comment: Gather multiple sets of columns with tidyr http://stackoverflow.com/q/25925556/5249203 Did you check this ? Is it not addressing your similar problem ? Possible duplicate ?

Comment: gather() come from package tidyr . soryy for not mentioning that before

Comment: Yes I have checked it: stackoverflow.com/q/25925556/5249203 but in my case column do not have similar names that all starting from same string so I have to use column number

Comment: I just saw this comment, that you need column numbers. You can either get column names for the `to_long` function with `colnames(data)[i+j]` or so, or you download the latest [GitHub-build of sjmisc](https://github.com/sjPlot/sjmisc), which supports numeric column indices as well (see `?to_long` for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to_long` function from the [sjmisc-package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc) for this purpose. This function is a convenient for-loop, which calls multiple `gather()` calls.

```
# create sample
mydat <- data.frame(age = c(20, 30, 40),
                    sex = c("Female", "Male", "Male"),
                    score_t1 = c(30, 35, 32),
                    score_t2 = c(33, 34, 37),
                    score_t3 = c(36, 35, 38),
                    speed_t1 = c(2, 3, 1),
                    speed_t2 = c(3, 4, 5),
                    speed_t3 = c(1, 8, 6))

# check tidyr. score is gathered, however, speed is not
tidyr::gather(mydat, "time", "score", score_t1, score_t2, score_t3)

>   age    sex speed_t1 speed_t2 speed_t3     time score
> 1  20 Female        2        3        1 score_t1    30
> 2  30   Male        3        4        8 score_t1    35
> 3  40   Male        1        5        6 score_t1    32
> 4  20 Female        2        3        1 score_t2    33
> 5  30   Male        3        4        8 score_t2    34
> 6  40   Male        1        5        6 score_t2    37
> 7  20 Female        2        3        1 score_t3    36
> 8  30   Male        3        4        8 score_t3    35
> 9  40   Male        1        5        6 score_t3    38

# gather multiple columns. both time and speed are gathered.
to_long(mydat, "time", c("score", "speed"),
        c("score_t1", "score_t2", "score_t3"),
        c("speed_t1", "speed_t2", "speed_t3"))

>     age    sex     time score speed
>   (dbl) (fctr)    (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
> 1    20 Female score_t1    30     2
> 2    30   Male score_t1    35     3
> 3    40   Male score_t1    32     1
> 4    20 Female score_t2    33     3
> 5    30   Male score_t2    34     4
> 6    40   Male score_t2    37     5
> 7    20 Female score_t3    36     1
> 8    30   Male score_t3    35     8
> 9    40   Male score_t3    38     6
```

In this case, the `time` vector (indicating the gathered groups) just takes one of the multiple gathered column name. If this is too confusing, you can also just number the ID variable:

```
to_long(mydat, "time", c("score", "speed"),
        c("score_t1", "score_t2", "score_t3"),
        c("speed_t1", "speed_t2", "speed_t3"),
        recode.key = TRUE)

>     age    sex  time score speed
>   (dbl) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
> 1    20 Female     1    30     2
> 2    30   Male     1    35     3
> 3    40   Male     1    32     1
> 4    20 Female     2    33     3
> 5    30   Male     2    34     4
> 6    40   Male     2    37     5
> 7    20 Female     3    36     1
> 8    30   Male     3    35     8
> 9    40   Male     3    38     6
```

See `?to_long` for more examples.

I'm not sure, but I think I read something on GitHub that "multiple column gathering" is also planned for tidyr somewhen...