# Gather multiple groups of columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a wide dataframe that I need to gather or melt into a tall dataframe. 
The part that I'm stuck on is that I have groups of columns that need to remain associated/grouped.

I have 2 users for each form submission and 3 columns of data for each user. I'd like to take these 6 columns and essentially stack them in groups of 3 so that each user is a separate observation.

This is a sample of more or less what my data looks like:

```
wide <- data.frame(
    form.ID     = c(1, 2), 
    entry.date  = c("2016-07-01", "2016-06-15"), 
    user.1      = c("Joe", "Sam"), 
    user.1.ID   = c("A1", "A2"), 
    user.1.data = c("foo", "lorem"),
    user.2      = c("Jane", "Sue"), 
    user.2.ID   = c("B1", "B2"),
    user.2.data = c("bar", "ipsum")
)

wide
#   form.ID entry.date user.1 user.1.ID user.1.data user.2 user.2.ID user.2.data
# 1       1 2016-07-01    Joe        A1         foo   Jane        B1         bar
# 2       2 2016-06-15    Sam        A2       lorem    Sue        B2       ipsum
```

This is the desired end state:

```
#   form.ID  entry.date   user   user.ID   user.data
# 1       1  2016-07-01    Joe        A1         foo
# 1       1  2016-07-01   Jane        B1         bar
# 2       2  2016-06-15    Sam        A2       lorem    
# 2       2  2016-06-15    Sue        B2       ipsum
```

I found this question, but I can't get the given answers to work in my case:

[Gather multiple sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns-with-tidyr)

I tried:

```
tall.almost <- gather(wide, user.n, user.name, user.1, user.2)
tall.almost
#   form.ID entry.date user.1.ID user.1.data user.2.ID user.2.data user.n user.name
# 1       1 2016-07-01        A1         foo        B1         bar user.1       Joe
# 2       2 2016-06-15        A2       ipsum        B2       lorem user.1       Sam
# 3       1 2016-07-01        A1         foo        B1         bar user.2      Jane
# 4       2 2016-06-15        A2       ipsum        B2       lorem user.2       Sue
```

I thought to use a sequence of gather() functions like the one above, but I get a duplicate data.

I tried:

```
tall.not.quite <- gather(wide, user.n, user.name, -form.ID, -date)
tall.not.quite
   form.ID entry.date      user.n user.name
1        1 2016-07-01      user.1       Joe
2        2 2016-06-15      user.1       Sam
3        1 2016-07-01   user.1.ID        A1
4        2 2016-06-15   user.1.ID        A2
5        1 2016-07-01 user.1.data       foo
6        2 2016-06-15 user.1.data     ipsum
7        1 2016-07-01      user.2      Jane
8        2 2016-06-15      user.2       Sue
9        1 2016-07-01   user.2.ID        B1
10       2 2016-06-15   user.2.ID        B2
11       1 2016-07-01 user.2.data       bar
12       2 2016-06-15 user.2.data     lorem
```

thinking I could then use spread() to pull out the user.n.ID and user.n.data fields, but I can't get that to work either. I end up back where I started.

I'm pretty good and stuck. This R newby would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Base R could also get you there after some renaming: `names(wide)[3:8] <- c("name.1","id.1","data.1","name.2","id.2","data.2"); reshape(wide, idvar=c("form.ID","entry.date"), direction="long", varying=3:8)` - not really worth an answer since you're working in the dplyr world.

Comment: I didn't mean to limit the scope of answers with how I structured the question. I actually find your answer easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` columns.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(wide), measure = patterns("\\d+$", "user.*ID$", "data$"),
   value.name = c("user", "user.ID", "user.data"))[,
    variable:= NULL][order(form.ID)]
#     form.ID entry.date user user.ID user.data
# 1:       1 2016-07-01  Joe      A1       foo
# 2:       1 2016-07-01 Jane      B1       bar
# 3:       2 2016-06-15  Sam      A2     lorem
# 4:       2 2016-06-15  Sue      B2     ipsum
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. You just saved me many (more) hours of head scratching. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't want to close this question just yet. While your solution worked on my dummy data, I'm getting errors on my real data set. I'm new to the data.table package so I wanted to try and investigate it first before coming back here with a follow up question. Don't worry I won't disappear. :)

Comment: @aaron No problem.  I would check the column names.  Here I used the regex patterns based on the column names showed in your post.