# tidyr::gather multiple columns of varying types

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns-with-tidyr). I'm trying to `tidyr::gather` multiple columns. However, the solution provided in the link is less than ideal because the attributes are generally not identical across all columns and so they are dropped.

Note, I know how to do this with base R, but I'm trying to learn how to do the equivalent operation with tidyr and/or dplyr.

Below I've simulated some data (poorly, but quickly) that illustrate the situation I often find myself in (although I generally have far more columns that follow this same sort of a pattern). I've provided the base solution with `stats::reshape` so you can see my desired output.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
set.seed(123)
male_g6 <- rbinom(100, 1, .5)
ell_g6 <- rbinom(100, 1, .1)
sped_g6 <- rbinom(100, 1, .15)
pullouts_g6 <- rbinom(100, 5, .1)
disability_g6 <- replicate(100, 
                sample(
                    c("asd", "cd", "ed", "hi", "id", "ohi", "ld", "none"),
                    1,
                    prob = c(rep(0.01, 6), 0.05, 0.89)
                    )
                 )
score_g6 <- rnorm(100, 200, 10)
score_g7 <- score_g6 + 5 + rnorm(100, 0, 2)
score_g8 <- score_g7 + 5 + rnorm(100, 0, 2)

d <- data.frame(
        SID = 1:100,
        male_g6 = male_g6,
        male_g7 = male_g6,
        male_g8 = male_g6,
        ell_g6 = ell_g6,
        ell_g7 = ell_g6,
        ell_g8 = ell_g6,
        sped_g6 = sped_g6,
        sped_g7 = sped_g6,
        sped_g8 = sped_g6,
        pullouts_g6 = pullouts_g6,
        pullouts_g7 = pullouts_g6,
        pullouts_g8 = pullouts_g6,
        disability_g6 = disability_g6,
        disability_g7 = disability_g6,
        disability_g8 = disability_g6,
        score_g6 = score_g6,
        score_g7 = score_g7,
        score_g8 = score_g8
    )
```

#### With base reshape

```
ld <- stats::reshape(d,
        idvar = "SID",
        varying = list(
            c("male_g6", "male_g7", "male_g8"),
            c("ell_g6", "ell_g7", "ell_g8"),
            c("sped_g6", "sped_g7", "sped_g8"),
            c("pullouts_g6", "pullouts_g7", "pullouts_g8"),
            c("disability_g6", "disability_g7", "disability_g8"),
            c("score_g6", "score_g7", "score_g8")
            ),
        v.names = c("male", "ell", "sped", "pullouts", "disability", "score"),
        times = 6:8,
        timevar = "Grade",
        direction = "long"
    )
ld <- ld[order(ld$SID), ]
```

Comment: As an aside, the base R reshape can be hugely simplified - `reshape(d, idvar="SID", direction="long", varying=2:19, sep="_g", timevar="Grade")` - `reshape` has some magical guessing of variable names and times if you specify an appropriate `sep=`

Comment: Sure. I was mostly just trying to provide an example of my desired output. I tend to name them all out of habit because the variables are generally all over the place and don't always have consistent names. But that is indeed simpler, and I like the use of `sep` in your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to gather beyond what you want to end with so you can separate the grade level from the headers, after which you can spread back to wide form:

```
ld2 <- d %>% gather(var, val, -SID) %>%     # gather to long form
    # separate grade from variable names
    separate(var, c('var', 'grade'), sep = '_g', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    spread(var, val, convert = TRUE)    # spread back to wide

head(ld2)

##   SID grade disability ell male pullouts    score sped
## 1   1     6         cd   0    0        1 196.2440    0
## 2   1     7         cd   0    0        1 203.2739    0
## 3   1     8         cd   0    0        1 211.1347    0
## 4   2     6       none   0    1        0 194.3812    1
## 5   2     7       none   0    1        0 195.3957    1
## 6   2     8       none   0    1        0 202.4890    1
```

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware of the `convert = TRUE` option. Much appreciated!