# Select multiple columns and reshape wide to long

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have wide dataset relating to cases and their contacts. (This is a made up example; the real dataset is much larger).

```
structure(list(record_id = structure(1:4, .Label = c("01-001", 
"01-002", "01-003", "01-004"), class = "factor"), place = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), age = c(4L, 
13L, 28L, 44L), d02_1 = c(2L, 2L, NA, 2L), d02_2 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", "F", "M"), class = "factor"), d02_3 = c(27L, 
16L, NA, 66L), d03_1 = c(3L, 3L, NA, 3L), d03_2 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "F", "M"), class = "factor"), d03_3 = c(14L, 
55L, NA, 12L), d04_1 = c(4L, NA, NA, NA), d04_2 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "M"), class = "factor"), d04_3 = c(7L, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("record_id", "place", "sex", "age", 
"d02_1", "d02_2", "d02_3", "d03_1", "d03_2", "d03_3", "d04_1", 
"d04_2", "d04_3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Where:

- record_id is the unique identifier of the case
- place is the place where the case lives
- age is case's age
- sex is case's sex
- d02_1, d03_1, d04_1 ... d0j_1  are contact's ids
- d02_2, d03_2, d04_2 ... d0j_2  are contact's sex
- d02_3, d03_3, d04_3 ... d0j_3  are contact's age

In the real dataset, there are potentially many contacts per case, and many more variables relating to contact's characteristics. Not all cases will have contacts.

I want to reshape the dataset to a tidy format, with one row per case/contact, ie:

```
         id case place sex age
1    01-001    1     a   M   4
2  01-001-2    0     a   M  27
3  01-001-3    0     a   M  14
4  01-001-4    0     a   M   7
5    01-002    1     b   M  13
6  01-002-2    0     b   F  16
7  01-002-3    0     b   M  55
8    01-003    1     a   F  28
9    01-004    1     a   M  44
10 01-004-2    0     a   M  66
11 01-004-3    0     a   F  12
```

I am thinking that I will need to create vectors of columns names relating to each contact (potentially using character-matching on column names), select these columns sequentially, and append them to each other (as well as concatenating the case/contact ids), but really struggling to without lots and lots of copying of lines of code. Must be a more efficient method?

Comment: Does this not help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229114/tidyrgather-multiple-columns-of-varying-types?rq=1. Seems like the same thing basically.

Comment: You should probably set `na.strings=''` when reading in. It doesn't make much sense / makes everything harder to have blanks there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

It is a `dplyr` solution that is ugly for a number of reasons, but I think it gets the job done.

```
DF <- DF %>%
  rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), gsub('_1','_ContactID',names(.)))) %>%
  rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), gsub('_2','_sex',names(.)))) %>%
  rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), gsub('_3','_age',names(.)))) %>%
  rename(d00_sex=sex,d00_age=age) %>%
  mutate(d00_ContactID=1) %>%
  gather(Var,Val,-record_id,-place) %>%
  mutate(Val =ifelse(Val=='',NA,Val)) %>%
  separate(Var,c('ContactLevel','Var'),sep='_') %>%
  spread(Var,Val) %>%
  arrange(record_id,ContactLevel) %>%
  filter(!is.na(age),!is.na(ContactID),!is.na(sex)) %>%
  mutate(age = as.numeric(age))
```

I start off by renaming your variables for clarity. (`rename_` lines)

Next, I put your case info variables into a consistent pattern where the case info is ContactID=1. (`ename` and `mutate` lines)

`Gather` turns the data from wide to long, but leaves us with one very ugly column and converts all your data to character. (This is the ugly part where the warning is triggered.)

`separate` splits the old column names into Contact ID and the data column.

`spread` then opens up the age, sex and ID into columns again. At this line these data are what you want, but can still be cleaned up a bit.

`arrange` is not necessary, but it puts all of the record IDs together.

`filter` is also not necessary, it just removes the rows with no contract information.

Finally, I use `mutate` to turn `age` from character to numeric. If you wish you can also turn sex into a factor here, and possibly contact ID as well.

Comment: Yes - this does the job. Nice use of setNames and gsub