# Using tidyverse gather() to output multiple value vectors with a single key in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

Despite the conventions of R, data collection and entry is for me most easily done in vertical columns. Therefore, I have a question about efficiently converting to horizontal rows with the gather() function in the tidyverse library. I find myself using gather() over and over which seems inefficient. Is there a more efficient way? And can an existing vector serve as the key? Here is an example:

Let's say we have the following health metrics on baby birds.

```
    bird day_1_mass day_2_mass day_1_heart_rate day_3_heart_rate
1    1          5          6               60               55
2    2          6          8               62               57
3    3          3          3               45               45
```

Using the gather function I can reorganize the mass data into rows.

```
horizontal.data <- gather(vertical.data,
                      key = age, 
                      value = mass, 
                      day_1_mass:day_2_mass, 
                      factor_key=TRUE)
```

Giving us

```
    bird day_1_heart_rate day_3_heart_rate        age mass
1    1               60               55 day_1_mass    5
2    2               62               57 day_1_mass    6
3    3               45               45 day_1_mass    3
4    1               60               55 day_2_mass    6
5    2               62               57 day_2_mass    8
6    3               45               45 day_2_mass    3
```

And use the same function again to similarly reorganize heart rate data.

```
horizontal.data.2 <- gather(horizontal.data, 
                            key = age2, 
                            value = heart_rate, 
                            day_1_heart_rate:day_3_heart_rate, 
                            factor_key=TRUE)
```

Producing a new dataframe

```
     bird        age mass             age2 heart_rate
1     1 day_1_mass    5 day_1_heart_rate         60
2     2 day_1_mass    6 day_1_heart_rate         62
3     3 day_1_mass    3 day_1_heart_rate         45
4     1 day_2_mass    6 day_1_heart_rate         60
5     2 day_2_mass    8 day_1_heart_rate         62
6     3 day_2_mass    3 day_1_heart_rate         45
7     1 day_1_mass    5 day_3_heart_rate         55
8     2 day_1_mass    6 day_3_heart_rate         57
9     3 day_1_mass    3 day_3_heart_rate         45
10    1 day_2_mass    6 day_3_heart_rate         55
11    2 day_2_mass    8 day_3_heart_rate         57
12    3 day_2_mass    3 day_3_heart_rate         45
```

So it took two steps, but it worked. The questions are 1) Is there a way to do this in one step? and 2) Can it alternatively be done with one key (the "age" vector) that I can then simply replace as numeric data?

Comment: Why don't you just use pipe function to combine both steps. I don't think there would be a way to include your desired operation within one `gather()` function >> `gather(vertical.data, key = age, value = mass, day_1_mass:day_2_mass, factor_key=TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key = age2, value = heart_rate, day_1_heart_rate:day_3_heart_rate, factor_key=TRUE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gather multiple sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns)

Answer (score 1):

if I get the question right, you could do that by first gathering everything together, and then "spreading" on mass and heart rate:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

mass_levs       <- names(vertical.data)[grep("mass", names(vertical.data))]
hearth_levs     <- names(vertical.data)[grep("heart", names(vertical.data))]
horizontal.data <- vertical.data %>% 
                     gather(variable, value, -bird,  factor_key = TRUE) %>% 
                     mutate(day = stringr::str_sub(variable, 5,5)) %>% 
                     mutate(variable = fct_collapse(variable,  
                                                    "mass" = mass_levs, 
                                                    "hearth_rate" = hearth_levs)) %>% 
                     spread(variable, value)
```

, giving:

```
  bird day mass hearth_rate
1    1   1    5          60
2    1   2    6          NA
3    1   3   NA          55
4    2   1    6          62
5    2   2    8          NA
6    2   3   NA          57
7    3   1    3          45
8    3   2    3          NA
9    3   3   NA          45
```

we can see how it works by going through the pipe one pass at a time.
First, we gather everyting on a long format:

```
horizontal.data <- vertical.data %>% 
                     gather(variable, value, -bird,  factor_key = TRUE)

  bird         variable value
1     1       day_1_mass     5
2     2       day_1_mass     6
3     3       day_1_mass     3
4     1       day_2_mass     6
5     2       day_2_mass     8
6     3       day_2_mass     3
7     1 day_1_heart_rate    60
8     2 day_1_heart_rate    62
9     3 day_1_heart_rate    45
10    1 day_3_heart_rate    55
11    2 day_3_heart_rate    57
12    3 day_3_heart_rate    45
```

then, if we want to keep a "proper" long table, as the OP suggested we have to create a single `key` variable. In this case, it makes sense to use the day (= age). To create the `day` variable, we can extract it from the character strings now in `variable`:

```
%>% mutate(day = stringr::str_sub(variable, 5,5))
```

here, str_sub gets the substring in position 5, which is the day (note that if in the full dataset you have multiple-digits days, you'll have to tweak this a bit, probably by splitting on `_`):

```
   bird         variable value day
1     1       day_1_mass     5   1
2     2       day_1_mass     6   1
3     3       day_1_mass     3   1
4     1       day_2_mass     6   2
5     2       day_2_mass     8   2
6     3       day_2_mass     3   2
7     1 day_1_heart_rate    60   1
8     2 day_1_heart_rate    62   1
9     3 day_1_heart_rate    45   1
10    1 day_3_heart_rate    55   3
11    2 day_3_heart_rate    57   3
12    3 day_3_heart_rate    45   3
```

now, to finish we have to "spread " the table to have a `mass` and a `heart rate` column.

Here we have a problem, because currently there are 2 levels each corresponding to mass and hearth rate in the `variable` column. Therefore, applying `spread` on `variable` would give us again four columns.

To prevent that, we need to aggregate the four levels in `variable` into two levels. We can do that by using `forcats::fc_collapse`, by providing the association between the new level names and the "old" ones. Outside of a pipe, that would correspond to:

```
horizontal.data$variable <- fct_collapse(horizontal.data$variable, 
                                mass = c("day_1_mass", "day_2_mass",
                                heart = c("day_1_hearth_rate", "day_3_heart_rate")
```

However, if you have many levels it is cumbersome to write them all. Therefore, I find beforehand the level names corresponding to the two "categories" using

```
mass_levs       <- names(vertical.data)[grep("mass", names(vertical.data))]
hearth_levs     <- names(vertical.data)[grep("heart", names(vertical.data))]
```

> mass_levs
>   [1] "day_1_mass" "day_2_mass"
>     hearth_levs
>   [1] "day_1_heart_rate" "day_3_heart_rate"

therefore, the third line of the pipe can be shortened to:

```
%>% mutate(variable = fct_collapse(variable,  
                              "mass" = mass_levs, 
                              "hearth_rate" = hearth_levs))
```

, after which we have:

```
  bird    variable value day
1     1        mass     5   1
2     2        mass     6   1
3     3        mass     3   1
4     1        mass     6   2
5     2        mass     8   2
6     3        mass     3   2
7     1 hearth_rate    60   1
8     2 hearth_rate    62   1
9     3 hearth_rate    45   1
10    1 hearth_rate    55   3
11    2 hearth_rate    57   3
12    3 hearth_rate    45   3
```

, so that we are now in the condition to "spread" the table again according to `variable` using:

```
%>% spread(variable, value)

  bird day mass hearth_rate
1    1   1    5          60
2    1   2    6          NA
3    1   3   NA          55
4    2   1    6          62
5    2   2    8          NA
6    2   3   NA          57
7    3   1    3          45
8    3   2    3          NA
9    3   3   NA          45
```

HTH

Comment: Yeah that works beautifully and is an elegant script. It would serve to better "teach a man to fish" as it were if you could annotate a bit, specifically what you're doing within mutate with stringr(?), and fct_collapse.

Comment: Ok. no it should be much more clear. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on a single command , i can give you one

setup the data.frame

```
c1<-c(1,2,3)
c2<-c(5,6,3)
c3<-c(6,8,3)
c4<-c(60,62,45)
c5<-c(55,57,45)
dt<-as.data.table(cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))
colnames(dt)<-c("bird","day_1_mass","day_2_mass","day_1_heart_rate","day_3_heart_rate")
```

Now use this single command to get the final outcome

```
merge(melt(dt[,c("bird","day_1_mass","day_2_mass")],id.vars = c("bird"),variable.name = "age",value.name="mass"),melt(dt[,c("bird","day_1_heart_rate","day_3_heart_rate")],id.vars = c("bird"),variable.name = "age2",value.name="heart_rate"),by = "bird")
```

The final outcome is

```
     bird        age     mass             age2 heart_rate
 1:    1 day_1_mass         5 day_1_heart_rate         60
 2:    1 day_1_mass         5 day_3_heart_rate         55
 3:    1 day_2_mass         6 day_1_heart_rate         60
 4:    1 day_2_mass         6 day_3_heart_rate         55
 5:    2 day_1_mass         6 day_1_heart_rate         62
 6:    2 day_1_mass         6 day_3_heart_rate         57
 7:    2 day_2_mass         8 day_1_heart_rate         62
 8:    2 day_2_mass         8 day_3_heart_rate         57
 9:    3 day_1_mass         3 day_1_heart_rate         45
10:    3 day_1_mass         3 day_3_heart_rate         45
11:    3 day_2_mass         3 day_1_heart_rate         45
12:    3 day_2_mass         3 day_3_heart_rate         45
```

Answer (score 0):

Though already answered, I have a different solution in which you save a list of the gather parameters you would like to run, and then run the gather_() command for each set of parameters in the list.

```
# Create a list of gather parameters
# Format is key, value, columns_to_gather
gather.list <- list(c("age", "mass", "day_1_mass", "day_2_mass"),
                    c("age2", "heart_rate", "day_1_heart_rate", "day_3_heart_rate"))

# Run gather command for each list item
for(i in gather.list){
  df <- gather_(df, key_col = i[1], value_col = i[2], gather_cols = c(i[3:length(i)]), factor_key = TRUE)
}
```