# Long to wide on multiple columns by data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question about `data.table`'s `melt` and `dcast` for multiple columns. I browsed on StackOverFlow but many similar posts are not what I want. I will explain below.

First, `data` is about causes of problems and the value amount. Here is my part of `data`:

```
ID   Type    Problem1    Value1     Problem2    Value2    Problem3    Value3
1    A       X           500        Y           1000      Z           400
2    A       X           600        Z           700       
3    B       Y           700        Z           100
4    B       W           200        V           200
5    C       Z           500        V           500       
6    C       X           1000       W           100       V           900
```

Second, `ID` is unique. `Type` contains three(`A`, `B`, and `C`). There are **5** problems.

Take `ID == 1` as an example. It is `Type A` and it contains 3 problems(`X`, `Y`, and `Z`). Its `Problem X` has `Value 500`, `Problem Y` has `Value 1000`, `Problem Z` has `Value 400`. Take `ID == 5` as an example. It is `Type C` and contains 2 problems(`Z` and `V`). Its `Problem Z` has `Value 500` and `Problem V` has `Value 500`.

Third, column `ID`, `Type`, `Problem1`, `Problem2`, and `Problem3` are `character`. `Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3` are `numeric`.

The result what I want is:

```
Type    X     Y     Z     W     V
A       1100  1000  1100  0     0   
B       0     700   100   200   200
C       1000  0     500   100   1400
```

I don't know how to explain here properly. I want to group the `Type` and then summation each problem's vlaue. I think this is about *long to wide*. I found reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html). Second one may be useful. However, I have no idea where to begin. Any suggestions?

```
# data
dt <- fread("
ID   Type    Problem1    Value1     Problem2    Value2    Problem3    Value3
1    A       X           500        Y           1000      Z           400
2    A       X           600        Z           700       
3    B       Y           700        Z           100
4    B       W           200        V           200
5    C       Z           500        V           500       
6    C       X           1000       W           100       V           900", fill = T)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can first `melt` by specifying the `patterns` in `measure` to 'long' format and then do the `dcast` with the `fun.aggregate` as `sum`

```
dcast(melt(dt, measure = patterns("^Value", "^Problem"), 
    value.name = c("Value", "Problem"))[Problem != ""
     ][, Problem := factor(Problem, levels = c("X", "Y", "Z", "W", "V"))], 
     Type ~Problem, value.var = "Value", sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#   Type    X    Y    Z   W    V
#1:    A 1100 1000 1100   0    0
#2:    B    0  700  100 200  200
#3:    C 1000    0  500 100 1400
```

`melt` from `data.table` can take multiple `patterns` in the `measure` argument.  So, when we say `"^Value"` it matches all the columns that have names that start (`^`) with "Value" and similarly for "Problem" and create two 'value' columns.  In the above, we are naming those columns as 'Value' and 'Problem' with `value.name` argument.  As the dataset having some blanks, the long format also have the blank elements which we remove with `Problem != ""`.  The next step is only important if we need to have the columns in a specific order.  So, we change the 'Problem' to `factor` class and specified the `levels` in that order.  Now, the `melt` part is completed.  The long format is now changed to 'wide' with `dcast` by specifying the formula, `value.var` column and the `fun.aggregate` (here it is `sum`)

Comment: Great answer. However, can u explain this in more detail way. `data.table` is awesome but it is not straightforward to see complex syntax like above answer. Thank you!

Comment: @akrun great answer! And good usage of function passing to dcast.

Comment: @PeterChen  Added more description.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Dummy and straightforward way, but still works (hope that someone can help to improve my solution).

```
library(magrittr)
rbind(
    dt[, .(Type, P = Problem1, V = Value1)],
    dt[, .(Type, P = Problem2, V = Value2)],
    dt[, .(Type, P = Problem3, V = Value3)]) %>%
    .[P != ""] %>%
    dcast(Type ~ P, value.var = "V", sum)
```

**Edit** Improved by following akrun's code (passing function to `dcast`).

Comment: I'd follow the same logic for the data.table answer and use gather and spread if you're in the dplyr/tidyr/pipe world.

Comment: `dplyr/tidyr/pipe ` is great. However, `data.table` is faster on large data.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done quite easily with dplyr / tidyr:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

# assume x is your dataframe
bind_rows(
  select(x, ID, Type, Problem = Problem1, Value = Value1),
  select(x, ID, Type, Problem = Problem2, Value = Value2),
  select(x, ID, Type, Problem = Problem3, Value = Value3)
  ) %>%
filter(!(is.na(Problem))) %>%
group_by(Type, Problem) %>%
summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
spread(Problem, Value, fill = 0)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   Type [3]
   Type     V     W     X     Y     Z
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     A     0     0  1100  1000  1100
2     B   200   200     0   700   100
3     C  1400   100  1000     0   500
```

If the order of columns V - Z is important this can be easily fixed by adding a final select statement.

Comment: There are also methods to do a multiple gather in dpylr/tidyr - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that uses the `melt` function that akrun performs and then uses matrix subsetting to return the desired result.

```
# melt and aggregate the data
temp <- melt(dt, measure = patterns("^Value", "^Problem"),
             value.name = c("Value", "Problem"))[
        !is.na(Value), .(Value=sum(Value)), by=.(Type, Problem)]

# set up the storage matrix
dimNames <- list(sort(unique(temp$Type)), unique(temp$Problem))
myMat <- matrix(0, length(dimNames[[1]]), length(dimNames[[2]]), dimnames=dimNames)

# fill in the matrix with the desired values
myMat[cbind(temp$Type, temp$Problem)] <- temp$Value
```

This returns the matrix

```
myMat
     X    Y   W    Z    V
A 1100 1000   0 1100    0
B    0  700 200  100  200
C 1000    0 100  500 1400
```

To return a data.table, you can do

```
data.table(myMat, keep.rownames=TRUE)
   rn    X    Y   W    Z    V
1:  A 1100 1000   0 1100    0
2:  B    0  700 200  100  200
3:  C 1000    0 100  500 1400
```