# Reshape a data frame that have multiple keys in column names from wide to long

Tags: r

I know that are already a lot of reshaping pages, but I did not find what I want and my problem is kind of unique.

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(Year=rep(1:4,4),id=rep(1:4,each=4),key1equals1.key2equals1.key3equals1=1,key1equals2.key2equals1.key3equals1=2,key1equals1.key2equals2.key3equals2=3,key1equals2.key2equals1.key3equals2=4)
```

Essentially, there are five keys: Year, id, key1, key2, key3

The value of key1, key2, key3 are all included in the column names.

I want to following dataset:

```
Year id key1 key2 key3 value
```

If possible, I want to use base R.

Comment: Please show the desired resulting data.frame, otherwise it's unlcear what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing inspiration from Hadley's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25932131/1854907):

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Year, -id) %>%
  extract(key, c("key1", "key2", "key3"), 'key1equals([0-9])\\.key2equals([0-9])\\.key3equals([0-9])')
```