# r - gather multiple columns in multiple key columns with tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

Not sure if `tidyr::gather` can be used to take multiple columns and merge them in multiple key columns.

Similar questions have been asked but they all refer to gathering multiple columns in one key column.

I'm trying to gather 4 columns into 2 key and 2 value columns like in the following example:

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    subject = c("a", "b"),
    age1 = c(33, 35),
    age2 = c(43, 45),
    weight1 = c(90, 67),
    weight2 = c(70, 87)
)

  subject age1 age2 weight1 weight2
1       a   33   43      90      70
2       b   35   45      67      87
```

Desired result:

```
dfe <- data.frame(
    subject = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
    age = c("age1", "age2", "age1", "age2"),
    age_values = c(33, 43, 35, 45),
    weight = c("weight1", "weight2", "weight1", "weight2"),
    weight_values = c(90, 70, 67, 87)
)

  subject  age age_values  weight weight_values
1       a age1         33 weight1            90
2       a age2         43 weight2            70
3       b age1         35 weight1            67
4       b age2         45 weight2            87
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gather multiple sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns)

Comment: Is there an update on this w.r.t. to accomplishing it with `pivot_longer()`, `pivot_wider()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it -

```
df %>%
  gather(key = "age", value = "age_values", age1, age2) %>%
  gather(key = "weight", value = "weight_values", weight1, weight2) %>%
  filter(substring(age, 4) == substring(weight, 7))

  subject  age age_values  weight weight_values
1       a age1         33 weight1            90
2       b age1         35 weight1            67
3       a age2         43 weight2            70
4       b age2         45 weight2            87
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach.  The idea is to do the use `gather`, then `split` the resulting dataframe by variable (age and weight), do the `mutate` operations separately for each of the two dataframes, then merge the dataframes back together using `subject` and the variable number (1 or 2).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  gather(age1:weight2, key = key, value = value) %>%
  separate(key, sep = -1, into = c("var", "num")) %>%
  split(.$var) %>%
  map(~mutate(., !!.$var[1] := paste0(var, num), !!paste0(.$var[1], "_values") := value)) %>%
  map(~select(., -var, -value)) %>%
  Reduce(f = merge, x = .) %>%
  select(-num)
```