# How to arrange a daily time series rainfall data to a single column?

Tags: r

My data frame comprises: 1st column is date ( consist of normal and leap year) , 2nd to 32 column is day ( day 1 , day 2... day 31)
How to arrange this dataset to a single column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Sounds like a reshaping issue. Have you tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to R (and also to SO, at least with answering) but I would use `gather` from the `tidyr` package for this task.

It's a bit hard to imagine your data without an example, so I'll make my own (Actually I don't see why there should be a date in the first column and then other columns for every single day):

```
  Date       day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 ... day_31
  ----       ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ... ------
1 2019-05-01     1     1     1     0     0     5 ...      6
2 2019-05-02     4     0     2     1     4     5 ...      4
3 2019-05-03     3     2     5     0     5     2 ...      2
```

You can use `gather` to convert your columns to rows the following.

```
gather(Data, key = "Day", value = "Rainfall", 2:32)
```

The first parameter (`Data`) is your dataset. The `key` parameter defines, what name your 'Key' column should have and `value` defines the name of the value column. The `2:32` part means, that you want columns 2 to 32 included in the result. If you have no other columns than the ones you mentioned you could also use `-1` instead of `2:32`, which just means to ignore the first colum.

This would give you the following result:

```
         Date    Day Rainfall
1  2019-05-01  day_1        1
2  2019-05-02  day_1        4
3  2019-05-03  day_1        3
4  2019-05-01  day_2        1
5  2019-05-02  day_2        0
6  2019-05-03  day_2        2
7  2019-05-01  day_3        1
8  2019-05-02  day_3        2
9  2019-05-03  day_3        5
10 2019-05-01  day_4        0
11 2019-05-02  day_4        1
...
...
...
```