# Pivot_longer to separate single columns into multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I inherited a dataset from a colleague that I'd like to analyze in R in long-form (currently wide-format data). Here's a subset of the data:

```r
    structure(list(Phase = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L), .Label = c("1_baseline", "2_first_10mins", "3_second_10mins", 
    "4_final_10mins"), class = "factor"), MaleID = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Weight_g = c(48.91, 84.81, 48.91, 84.81, 
    48.91, 84.81, 48.91, 84.81), FemaleID = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), Female_side = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("Left", "Right"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("7/11/2016 10:53", "7/11/2016 9:26"
    ), class = "factor"), Trx = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "G1", class = "factor"), Center_All_TotalDistMoved = c(2385, 
    3284.86, 1612.03, 2656.36, 1674.68, 1174.75, 1543.54, 629.412
    ), Nose_Left_CumDur = c(112.64, 248.32, 64.24, 91.12, 82.56, 
    22.8, 71.88, 16.48), Nose_Left_FreqZoneEntry = c(260L, 602L, 
    60L, 208L, 77L, 16L, 139L, 10L), Nose_Left_LatencyFirstEntry = c(4.6, 
    0.08, 1571.84, 1560, 2168.16, 2161.96, 2776.28, 2790.72), Nose_Right_CumDur = c(92.4, 
    40.48, 194.88, 426.96, 188.76, 500.44, 93.92, 559.56), Nose_Right_FreqZoneEntry = c(174L, 
    100L, 257L, 229L, 277L, 159L, 182L, 54L), Nose_Right_LatencyFirstEntry = c(0.12, 
    117.44, 1565.2, 1660.72, 2160, 2165.4, 2790.2, 2760.76), Nose_Dead_CumDur = c(327.68, 
    112.88, 176.84, 25.16, 143.44, 45.32, 314.48, 12.16), Nose_Dead_FreqZoneEntry = c(536L, 
    722L, 370L, 142L, 437L, 148L, 455L, 52L), Nose_Dead_LatencyFirstEntry = c(0, 
    0, 1562.92, 1684.04, 2160.6, 2160, 2760, 2760), Center_Left_CumDur = c(73.2, 
    260.96, 37.24, 102.68, 46.16, 20.32, 32.92, 17.52), Center_Left_FreqZoneEntry = c(23L, 
    74L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 14L, 1L), Center_Left_LatencyFirstEntry = c(108.16, 
    0, 1792.32, 1560, 2170.76, 2162.8, 2804.04, 2792.4), Center_Right_CumDur = c(63.16, 
    25.44, 154, 415.56, 131.16, 475.4, 64.28, 541.68), Center_Right_FreqZoneEntry = c(10L, 
    8L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 22L, 29L, 13L), Center_Right_LatencyFirstEntry = c(121.64, 
    139.04, 1673.12, 1661.84, 2160, 2166.08, 2790.72, 2760), Center_Dead_CumDur = c(441.64, 
    101.76, 243.56, 62.76, 198, 87.88, 430.28, 32.4), Center_Dead_FreqZoneEntry = c(34L, 
    72L, 38L, 23L, 37L, 26L, 46L, 8L), Center_Dead_LatencyFirstEntry = c(0, 
    20.28, 1560, 1706.4, 2160.96, 2160, 2760, 2770.84), Center_All_MeanVelocity = c(3.98271, 
    5.4766, 2.68744, 4.42786, 2.79113, 1.95818, 2.57738, 1.05056)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L))
```

Within each of columns (specifically, columns 8 - 27), there's 3 factors/measurements that I want to extract:

1. Point (variables = Center; Nose);
2. Zone (variables = Left; Right; Dead);
3. Measurement (several variables:  TotalDistMoved, CumDur, FreqZoneEntry, LatencyFirstEntry, MeanVelocity).

Based on two similar posts here ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138600/tidy-dataset-with-pivot-longer-multiple-columns-into-two-columns), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211859/pivot-longer-to-create-multiple-combined-columns)) I tried to use the following code on a subset of my data (just one column first, then to scale up), but I'm very confused by regex, which I believe is part of my problem (not sure how to parse 3 columns/values based on "_" as separator):

```r
    df %>% 
      pivot_longer(Center_All_TotalDistMoved,
                   names_to = c("Point", ".value"),
                   names_pattern = "([^_]+)_(.*)")
```

This does an ok job, and parses out the "Point" factor:

```r
    # A tibble: 151 x 9
       Phase      MaleID Weight_g      FemaleID Female_side Date            Trx   Point  All_TotalDistMoved
       <fct>       <int> <fct>            <int> <fct>       <fct>           <fct> <chr>               <dbl>
     1 1_baseline      1 48.91                1 Right       7/11/2016 9:26  G1    Center              2385 
     2 1_baseline      2 84.81                2 Right       7/11/2016 10:53 G1    Center              3285.
     3 1_baseline      3 VERIFY_NUMBER        3 Right       7/12/2016 9:50  VEH   Center              2397.
     4 1_baseline      4 69.15                1 Left        7/12/2016 12:32 VEH   Center              4011.
     5 1_baseline      5 86.15                2 Left        7/13/2016 9:52  G1    Center              2746.
     6 1_baseline      6 60.17                3 Left        7/13/2016 11:30 G1    Center              1994.
     7 1_baseline      7 46.82                1 Left        7/14/2016 10:10 VEH   Center              2910.
     8 1_baseline      8 35.52                2 Left        7/14/2016 11:59 VEH   Center              1892.
     9 1_baseline      9 29.92                3 Right       7/15/2016 9:54  G1    Center              4823.
    10 1_baseline     10 28.96                1 Left        7/15/2016 11:32 G1    Center              2119.
```

However, I can't scale the above code up within the one column without an error due to my regex ignorance. Further, I'm unsure how to do this same operation across the rest of the columns, and still have the data matched by `MaleID` and `Phase`. **Ideally, this is what the dataframe should look like**:

```r
  MaleID Weight_g Treatment    Phase FemaleID FemaleLocation           Date  Point  Zone TotalDistMoved CumDur FreqZoneEntry LatencyFirstEntry MeanVelocity
1      1    48.91        G1 Baseline        1          Right 7/11/2016 9:26 Center   All           2385     NA            NA                NA      3.98271
2      1    48.91        G1 Baseline        1          Right 7/11/2016 9:26   Nose  Left             NA 112.64           260              4.60           NA
3      1    48.91        G1 Baseline        1          Right 7/11/2016 9:26   Nose Right             NA  92.40           174              0.12           NA
4      1    48.91        G1 Baseline        1          Right 7/11/2016 9:26   Nose  Dead             NA 327.68           536              0.00           NA
5      1    48.91        G1 Baseline        1          Right 7/11/2016 9:26 Center  Left             NA  73.20            23            108.16           NA
6      1    48.91        G1 Baseline        1          Right 7/11/2016 9:26 Center Right             NA  63.16            10            121.64           NA
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, figured it out! Thanks in part to @akrun for linking the related post when closing this one, I solved this issue with the following code:
`df %>%  pivot_longer(cols = c(8:27), names_to = c("Point", "Zone",".value"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)_(.*)")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Explanation of code:

1. As you specify that you are splitting column names into three variables: point, zone, measurement. You create three columns with these names using `names_to` argument.
2. In the `names_pattern` argument, using `(.*)_(.*)_(.*)` you can extract the three separators. Note that, this regex assumes that `_` is occuring only two times in column name. `.*` matches any word and `()` are used to extract words.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(8:27), 
                 names_to = c('point', 'zone', 'measurement'), 
                 names_pattern = '(.*)_(.*)_(.*)', 
                 values_to = 'amount') -> df2
df2
#> # A tibble: 160 x 11
#>    Phase MaleID Weight_g FemaleID Female_side Date  Trx   point zone 
#>    <fct>  <int>    <dbl>    <int> <fct>       <fct> <fct> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Cent~ All  
#>  2 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Left 
#>  3 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Left 
#>  4 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Left 
#>  5 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Right
#>  6 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Right
#>  7 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Right
#>  8 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Dead 
#>  9 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Dead 
#> 10 1_ba~      1     48.9        1 Right       7/11~ G1    Nose  Dead 
#> # ... with 150 more rows, and 2 more variables: measurement <chr>, amount <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @monte! It's almost what I need - however, is it possible to transform/retain the "measurement" variables as their own column? Specifically: TotalDistMoved; CumDur FreqZoneEntry; LatencyFirstEntry; MeanVelocity. Does that make sense? See the "ideal dataframe" from the post - apologies if my request was poorly phrased.