# Pivoting wider one column to multiple columns

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, transform, tidyr

I'm trying to pivot multiple values at a time.

I have this:

```
>  head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  variable       `Mean (SD)`    `Median (IQR)`
  <chr>          <glue>         <glue>        
1 VarA_VVV_Cond1 268.59 (80.6)  276 (86)      
2 VarA_WWW_Cond1 149.07 (39.79) 155 (40.5)    
3 VarA_XXX_Cond1 147.71 (39.65) 155 (41)      
4 VarA_YYY_Cond1 18.85 (10.76)  18 (15.5)     
5 VarA_ZZZ_Cond1 20.98 (11.34)  20 (14)       
6 VarA_VVV_Cond2 228.49 (83.77) 241 (116)
```

The desired output is this:

```
          VVV(Mean/SD) VVV(Median/IQR) XXX(Mean/SD) XXX(Median/IQR)... 
VAR_A_Cond_1
VAR_A_Cond_2
VAR_B_Cond_1
VAR_B_Cond_2
```

This is my dataset:

```
>  dput(data)
structure(list(variable = c("VarA_VVV_Cond1", "VarA_WWW_Cond1", 
"VarA_XXX_Cond1", "VarA_YYY_Cond1", "VarA_ZZZ_Cond1", "VarA_VVV_Cond2", 
"VarA_WWW_Cond2", "VarA_XXX_Cond2", "VarA_YYY_Cond2", "VarA_ZZZ_Cond2", 
"VarB_VVV_Cond1", "VarB_WWW_Cond1", "VarB_XXX_Cond1", "VarB_YYY_Cond1", 
"VarB_ZZZ_Cond1", "VarB_VVV_Cond2", "VarB_WWW_Cond2", "VarB_XXX_Cond2", 
"VarB_YYY_Cond2", "VarB_ZZZ_Cond2"), `Mean (SD)` = structure(c("268.59 (80.6)", 
"149.07 (39.79)", "147.71 (39.65)", "18.85 (10.76)", "20.98 (11.34)", 
"228.49 (83.77)", "113.66 (35.91)", "112.64 (35.75)", "24.07 (15.79)", 
"26.36 (16.51)", "250.72 (61.53)", "140.71 (30.52)", "138.93 (30.37)", 
"21.02 (10.46)", "22.72 (11.05)", "225.98 (81.32)", "112.43 (36.09)", 
"111.1 (36.41)", "24.71 (16.77)", "26.59 (17.49)"), class = c("glue", 
"character")), `Median (IQR)` = structure(c("276 (86)", "155 (40.5)", 
"155 (41)", "18 (15.5)", "20 (14)", "241 (116)", "116 (51)", 
"116 (48)", "23 (21.5)", "24 (22.5)", "259 (60)", "142 (36)", 
"142 (34)", "21 (15)", "21 (15)", "244.5 (93.5)", "107.5 (51.5)", 
"107 (50.75)", "24 (20.75)", "24.5 (21.75)"), class = c("glue", 
"character"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried many things, but nothing had solved the issue:

Like this:

```
data1 <- data %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_wider(.,
                      names_from = "variable",
                      values_from = c("Mean (SD)", "Median (IQR)")) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = 1:40,
   names_to = c("Names"),
   values_to = c("Mean_SD", "Median_IQR"))
```

Any thoughts??

Thanks in advance!

Additional info: I have 20 rows/obs in the original "data". Each is called: `VarA_VVV_Cond1`, which means that I have 2 variables: (`A` and `B`), 5 tests (`VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY, ZZZ`) and 2 conditions (`Cond1`, `Cond2`).

Given that, I also have the tests `Mean (SD)` and `Median (IQR)`. That's the idea.

Obs: I've seen many posts here concerning pivoting, but none seems to account for this (like this, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145833/gathering-wide-columns-into-multiple-long-columns-using-pivot-longer)...I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: The original  ```Mean (SD)``` and ```Median (IQR)``` values :) So that I'd have ten colluns (one for each test), like this: ````VVV(Mean/SD),  VVV(Median/IQR), ....."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may need to `separate` the column 'variable' before we do the pivoting to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   mutate(variable = str_replace(variable, "^(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)",
        "\\1_\\3,\\2")) %>% 
   separate(variable, into = c("variable", "newcol"), sep = ",") %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = newcol, values_from = c(`Mean (SD)`,
      `Median (IQR)`), names_glue = "{newcol}({.value})")%>% 
    rename_with(~ str_remove(str_replace(.x, "\\s+\\(", "/"), "\\)"), -variable)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 11
  variable   `VVV(Mean/SD)` `WWW(Mean/SD)` `XXX(Mean/SD)` `YYY(Mean/SD)` `ZZZ(Mean/SD)` `VVV(Median/IQR)` `WWW(Median/IQR)` `XXX(Median/IQR)` `YYY(Median/IQR)`
  <chr>      <glue>         <glue>         <glue>         <glue>         <glue>         <glue>            <glue>            <glue>            <glue>           
1 VarA_Cond1 268.59 (80.6)  149.07 (39.79) 147.71 (39.65) 18.85 (10.76)  20.98 (11.34)  276 (86)          155 (40.5)        155 (41)          18 (15.5)        
2 VarA_Cond2 228.49 (83.77) 113.66 (35.91) 112.64 (35.75) 24.07 (15.79)  26.36 (16.51)  241 (116)         116 (51)          116 (48)          23 (21.5)        
3 VarB_Cond1 250.72 (61.53) 140.71 (30.52) 138.93 (30.37) 21.02 (10.46)  22.72 (11.05)  259 (60)          142 (36)          142 (34)          21 (15)          
4 VarB_Cond2 225.98 (81.32) 112.43 (36.09) 111.1 (36.41)  24.71 (16.77)  26.59 (17.49)  244.5 (93.5)      107.5 (51.5)      107 (50.75)       24 (20.75)       
# … with 1 more variable: `ZZZ(Median/IQR)` <glue>
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe that the solution was THAT simple!!! Thank you, SO MUCH! If you don't mind, would you explain this regex part ```"^(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)",
        "\\1_\\3,\\2")) ``` ?

Comment: @LarissaCury The `(..)` syntax is for capturing some characters.  `\\w+` - matches the word from the start (`^`) of the string, and is captured, then matches the `_`, folllowed by capturing the second and third word as described earlier.  Then, we just rearrange the backreferences of the captured group so that we can split by a unique separator `,`.  The `rename_with` is also done so as to match your expected column name pattern

Comment: This is something  (regex) I'll have to study more, thank you! What If I wanted to put a space between ```ZZZ(Median/IQR)``` like ```ZZZ<here>(Median/IQR)``` ? I've tried " " , \s, but it didn't work... @akrun

Comment: @LarissaCury you can use `.. %>% pivot_wider(names_from = newcol, values_from = c(`Mean (SD)`,
      `Median (IQR)`), names_glue = "{newcol} ({.value})") %>%   rename_with(~ str_replace(.x, "\\s*\\((\\w+)\\)", "/\\1"), -variable)`

Comment: thank you! it worked! do you recommend any  introduction to regex?

Comment: @LarissaCury you could check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or [here](https://regexlearn.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate(variable, into = c("Var", "XXX", "Cond"), sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = XXX,
              values_from = c(`Mean (SD)`,`Median (IQR)`)) %>% 
  mutate(x = paste(Var, Cond, sep = "_"), .keep="unused", .before=1) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("x")
```

```
    Mean (SD)_VVV  Mean (SD)_WWW  Mean (SD)_XXX Mean (SD)_YYY Mean (SD)_ZZZ Median (IQR)_VVV Median (IQR)_WWW Median (IQR)_XXX Median (IQR)_YYY Median (IQR)_ZZZ
VarA_Cond1  268.59 (80.6) 149.07 (39.79) 147.71 (39.65) 18.85 (10.76) 20.98 (11.34)         276 (86)       155 (40.5)         155 (41)        18 (15.5)          20 (14)
VarA_Cond2 228.49 (83.77) 113.66 (35.91) 112.64 (35.75) 24.07 (15.79) 26.36 (16.51)        241 (116)         116 (51)         116 (48)        23 (21.5)        24 (22.5)
VarB_Cond1 250.72 (61.53) 140.71 (30.52) 138.93 (30.37) 21.02 (10.46) 22.72 (11.05)         259 (60)         142 (36)         142 (34)          21 (15)          21 (15)
VarB_Cond2 225.98 (81.32) 112.43 (36.09)  111.1 (36.41) 24.71 (16.77) 26.59 (17.49)     244.5 (93.5)     107.5 (51.5)      107 (50.75)       24 (20.75)     24.5 (21.75)
>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works too:

```
df[c('Var', 'Group', 'Cond')] <- str_split_fixed(df$variable, "_", n = Inf)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Var, Cond), 
              values_from = c(`Mean (SD)`, `Median (IQR)`), 
              names_from = Group)


Var   Cond  `Mean (SD)_VVV` `Mean (SD)_WWW` `Mean (SD)_XXX` `Mean (SD)_YYY` `Mean (SD)_ZZZ` `Median (IQR)_VVV`
  <chr> <chr> <glue>          <glue>          <glue>          <glue>          <glue>          <glue>            
1 VarA  Cond1 268.59 (80.6)   149.07 (39.79)  147.71 (39.65)  18.85 (10.76)   20.98 (11.34)   276 (86)          
2 VarA  Cond2 228.49 (83.77)  113.66 (35.91)  112.64 (35.75)  24.07 (15.79)   26.36 (16.51)   241 (116)         
3 VarB  Cond1 250.72 (61.53)  140.71 (30.52)  138.93 (30.37)  21.02 (10.46)   22.72 (11.05)   259 (60)          
4 VarB  Cond2 225.98 (81.32)  112.43 (36.09)  111.1 (36.41)   24.71 (16.77)   26.59 (17.49)   244.5 (93.5)
```