# create multiple variable/value columns with melt - R

Tags: r, reshape, melt

```
> df <- data.frame(g=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), foo_x=c(12,32,14,23,12,34), foo_y=c(32,35,12,12,32,34), bar_x=c(100,233,122,433,122,442), bar_y=c(744,546,236,137,652,235))
```

I'm trying to create this data frame:

```
g  foo  bar val_foo  val_bar
1   x    x     12      100
2   x    x     32      233
3   x    x     14      122
1   x    y     32      744
2   x    y     35      546
3   x    y     12      236
1   y    x     23      433
2   y    x     12      122
3   y    x     34      442
1   y    y     12      137
2   y    y     32      652
3   y    y     34      235
```

I think I should be using the `melt` function, but how can I create two different variable (`foo` and `bar`) and value (`val_foo` and `val_bar`) columns? `melt(df, id.vars="g")` only creates a single variable/value pair.

Comment: The `foo`, `bar` columns with names are not aligning with your iiput

Comment: Lots of relevant ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25925556/5325862)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` for multiple sets of columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -g, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), names_sep="_")
```

---

Or with `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^foo", "^bar"), 
      value.name = c("val_foo", "val_bar"))
```

---

Or as @markus mentioned with `base R`

```
reshape(df, idvar = "g", varying = list(2:3, 4:5), sep = "_",
    direction = "long", v.names = c("val_foo", "val_bar"), new.row.names = 1:12)
```

Comment: To complete the holy trinity: `reshape(df, idvar = "g", varying = list(2:3, 4:5), sep = "_", direction = "long", v.names = c("val_foo", "val_bar"), new.row.names = 1:12)`