# R reshape name value pairs from wide to long using pivot_longer

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I am trying to figure out how to reshape a dataset of the names of political parties from wide to long using `dplyr` and `pivot_longer`.

For each `Party_ID`, there is a number of constant columns attached `(Party_Name_Short, Party_Name, Country, Party_in_orig_title)` and a number of time changing factors as well: `election, Date, Rename, Reason, Party_Title, alliance, member_parties, split, parent_party, merger, child_party, successor, predecessor`. The time changing factors were recorded up to 11 times for each party, as reflected by the index in the colname.

In order to provide a sample I selected the first three time changing columns for each party and a sample of 5 random rows:

```
structure(list(Party_Name_Short = c("LZJ-PS", "ZiZi", "MNR", 
"MDP", "E200"), Party_Name = c("Lista Zorana Jankovica – Pozitivna Slovenija", 
"Živi zid", "Mouvement national républicain", "Movimento Democrático Português", 
"Erakond Eesti 200"), Country = c("SVN", "HRV", "FRA", "PRT", 
"EST"), Party_ID = c(1987, 2612, 1263, 1281, 2720), Party_in_orig_title = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Date1 = c(2011, NA, 1999, 1987, NA), Rename1 = c("Lista Zorana Jankovica – Pozitivna Slovenija", 
NA, "Mouvement national républicain", "ID", NA), Reason1 = c("foundation", 
NA, "split from FN", "split", NA), Party_Title1 = c(0, NA, 0, 
0, NA), alliance1 = c(0, NA, 0, 0, NA), member_parties1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    split1 = c(0, NA, 1, 1, NA), parent_party1 = c(NA, NA, "FN", 
    "MDP", NA), merger1 = c(0, NA, 0, 0, NA), child_party1 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), successor1 = c(0, NA, 0, 0, NA), predecessor1 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Date2 = c(2012, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rename2 = c("Pozitivna Slovenija", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Reason2 = c("renamed", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Party_Title2 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA), alliance2 = c(0, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), member_parties2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), split2 = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), parent_party2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), merger2 = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), child_party2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), successor2 = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), predecessor2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Date3 = c(2014, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Rename3 = c("ZaAB", NA, NA, NA, NA), Reason3 = c("split", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Party_Title3 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA), alliance3 = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), member_parties3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), split3 = c(1, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), parent_party3 = c("LZJ-PS", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), merger3 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA), child_party3 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), successor3 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA), predecessor3 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), election1 = structure(c(15309, 16740, 11839, 6390, 17956
    ), class = "Date"), election2 = structure(c(16252, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), class = "Date"), election3 = structure(c(16344, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like the data to follow a "long" structure where each party_id and the constant factors are repeated 11 times and there are single columns for the time changing factors. Following the top-rated answer formulated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns) I tried different variations of the following command:

```
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("election", "Date", "Rename", "Reason", "Party_Title",
                                    "alliance", "member_parties", "split", "parent_party",
                                    "merger", "child_party", "successor", "predecessor")), 
               names_to = c(".value", "election", "Date", "Rename", "Reason", "Party_Title",
                            "alliance", "member_parties", "split", "parent_party",
                            "merger", "child_party", "successor", "predecessor"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
    select(-matches("election[1-9]"), -matches("Date[1-9]"), -matches("Rename[1-9]"),
     -matches("Reason[1-9]"), -matches("alliance[1-9]"), -matches("member_parties[1-9]"),
     -matches("split[1-9]"), -matches("parent_party[1-9]"), -matches("merger[1-9]"),
     -matches("child_party[1-9]"), -matches("successor[1-9]"), -matches("predecessor[1-9]"),
     -matches("Party_Title[1-9]"), -matches("election1[0-2]"), -matches("Date1[0-2]"), -matches("Rename1[0-2]"),
     -matches("Reason1[0-2]"), -matches("alliance1[0-2]"), -matches("member_parties1[0-2]"),
     -matches("split1[0-2]"), -matches("parent_party1[0-2]"), -matches("merger1[0-2]"),
     -matches("child_party1[0-2]"), -matches("successor1[0-2]"), -matches("predecessor1[0-2]"),
     -matches("Party_Title1[0-2]"))
```

However, for some reason, I get a lot of missing values and do not achieve the shape of the data I would like to have. I'd appreciate any hint if you have an idea of how to do this. Thanks!

**Update**:

I would like the final output to look something like:

```
structure(list(Party_Name_Short = c("LZJ-PS", "ZiZi", "MNR", 
"MDP", "E200", "LZJ-PS", "ZiZi", "MNR", "MDP", "E200", "LZJ-PS", 
"ZiZi", "MNR", "MDP", "E200"), Party_Name = c("Lista Zorana Jankovica – Pozitivna Slovenija", 
"Živi zid", "Mouvement national républicain", "Movimento Democrático Português", 
"Erakond Eesti 200", "Lista Zorana Jankovica – Pozitivna Slovenija", 
"Živi zid", "Mouvement national républicain", "Movimento Democrático Português", 
"Erakond Eesti 200", "Lista Zorana Jankovica – Pozitivna Slovenija", 
"Živi zid", "Mouvement national républicain", "Movimento Democrático Português", 
"Erakond Eesti 200"), Country = c("SVN", "HRV", "FRA", "PRT", 
"EST", "SVN", "HRV", "FRA", "PRT", "EST", "SVN", "HRV", "FRA", 
"PRT", "EST"), Party_ID = c(1987, 2612, 1263, 1281, 2720, 1987, 
2612, 1263, 1281, 2720, 1987, 2612, 1263, 1281, 2720), Party_in_orig_title = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), time = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Date = c(2011, NA, 1999, 
1987, NA, 2012, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2014, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rename = c("Lista Zorana Jankovica – Pozitivna Slovenija", 
NA, "Mouvement national républicain", "ID", NA, "Pozitivna Slovenija", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "ZaAB", NA, NA, NA, NA), Reason = c("foundation", 
NA, "split from FN", "split", NA, "renamed", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"split", NA, NA, NA, NA), Party_Title = c(0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA), alliance = c(0, NA, 0, 0, 
NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA), member_parties = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), split = c(0, 
NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), parent_party = c(NA, 
NA, "FN", "MDP", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "LZJ-PS", NA, NA, NA, 
NA), merger = c(0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), child_party = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), successor = c(0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA), predecessor = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), election = structure(c(1322697600, 
1446336000, 1022889600, 552096000, 1551398400, 1404172800, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1412121600, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Notice: the newly added `time` column and notice that this is only for example purposes, with three time changing factors, whereas in fact there are 11 in the data.

Comment: can you  shsow your  expected output

Comment: I added now the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot_longer` with `names_sep` to split between a non-digit and a digit at the end of the string

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols =  matches('\\d+$'), names_to = c(".value", 'time'),
           names_sep="(?<=\\D)(?=\\d+$)") %>%
  arrange(time)
# A tibble: 15 x 19
#   Party_Name_Short Party_Name Country Party_ID Party_in_orig_t… time   Date Rename Reason Party_Title alliance member_parties split
#   <chr>            <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>            <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 LZJ-PS           Lista Zor… SVN         1987                0 1      2011 Lista… found…           0        0 <NA>               0
# 2 ZiZi             Živi zid   HRV         2612                0 1        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
# 3 MNR              Mouvement… FRA         1263                0 1      1999 Mouve… split…           0        0 <NA>               1
# 4 MDP              Movimento… PRT         1281                0 1      1987 ID     split            0        0 <NA>               1
# 5 E200             Erakond E… EST         2720                0 1        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
# 6 LZJ-PS           Lista Zor… SVN         1987                0 2      2012 Pozit… renam…           0        0 <NA>               0
# 7 ZiZi             Živi zid   HRV         2612                0 2        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
# 8 MNR              Mouvement… FRA         1263                0 2        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
# 9 MDP              Movimento… PRT         1281                0 2        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
#10 E200             Erakond E… EST         2720                0 2        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
#11 LZJ-PS           Lista Zor… SVN         1987                0 3      2014 ZaAB   split            0        0 <NA>               1
#12 ZiZi             Živi zid   HRV         2612                0 3        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
#13 MNR              Mouvement… FRA         1263                0 3        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
#14 MDP              Movimento… PRT         1281                0 3        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
#15 E200             Erakond E… EST         2720                0 3        NA <NA>   <NA>            NA       NA <NA>              NA
# … with 6 more variables: parent_party <chr>, merger <dbl>, child_party <chr>, successor <dbl>, predecessor <chr>, election <date>
```