# R: gather multiple sets of columns with tidyr pivot_longer()

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to gather two sets of columns.  Each set needs to end up in a new column, but the rows data is linked, so sequential uses of `tidyr::gather()` won't guarantee retention of cross-column organization.  It looks like `tidyr::pivot_longer()` can accomplish this, but I am stumped.  A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns), but the answer involves using grep to rename columns, which I can't unravel and also shouldn't be necessary here.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Position=1:5,
  A_Width=3:7,
  B_Width=4:8,
  A_Error=seq(0, 2.0, 0.5),
  B_Error=seq(0.3, 1.5, 0.3)
  )


df <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols=c(A_Width, B_Width, A_Error, B_Error),
    names_to= ? ,
    names_pattern= ? ,
    )

##Desired Data Frame
df_long <- data.frame(
  Position=rep(1:5,2),
  Group=c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5)),
  Width=c(3:7,4:8),
  Error=c(seq(0, 2.0, 0.5), seq(0.3, 1.5, 0.3))
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.value` with `names_to` to use the second part of the column names to specify the new columns those values should go to.

```
df |>
  pivot_longer(-Position, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("Group", ".value"))
```

Result (in order as encountered, could sort)

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Position Group Width Error
      <int> <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1        1 A         3   0  
 2        1 B         4   0.3
 3        2 A         4   0.5
 4        2 B         5   0.6
 5        3 A         5   1  
 6        3 B         6   0.9
 7        4 A         6   1.5
 8        4 B         7   1.2
 9        5 A         7   2  
10        5 B         8   1.5
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Can you elaborate on what `names_sep="_"` is doing here?  What if the Column names were `aWidth, bWidth, aError, bError` - would we need a different value for `names_sep`?  I can rename my columns to have a  `_` separator; I just want to wrap my head around this for future uses - the reference page isn't helping, heh.

Comment: @JVGen the `names_sep = '_'` defines the delimitor that separates the data names from the grouping. In case your data lacks it, you can use `names_pattern`. Otherwise, in an example like `aWidth, bWidth`..., you can clea the names with `janitor::clean_names` function for example

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no way to explicitly call the columns to be grouped?  For instance something like `Position, Width=c(aWidth,bWidth), Error=c(aError,bError)`?  That's the most intuitive for me, but I am unfamiliar with string pattern manipulation.  I was able to add a `_` to my column names so Jon's solution is working.

Comment: @JVGen there is a way to explicitly call the columns to be grouped. Although that is in `data.table`  using `patterns` argument within `melt` function

Comment: For the examples like `aWidth`, you could use `names_sep = 1` to split after the first letter. Other regex possible if you wanted to split at the first capital letter, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Position) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("Group", "x"), sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x)

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Position Group Width Error
      <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1        1 A         3   0  
 2        1 B         4   0.3
 3        2 A         4   0.5
 4        2 B         5   0.6
 5        3 A         5   1  
 6        3 B         6   0.9
 7        4 A         6   1.5
 8        4 B         7   1.2
 9        5 A         7   2  
10        5 B         8   1.5
```